# pythonic way of decorating classmethods

Tags: python, python-decorators

Given the following example:

```
class A:
    def f(self, x):
        return 2*x
```

I would like to write another method which uses `f` above but adds a constant, i.e.

```
class A:
        def f(self, x):
            return 2*x
        def g(self, x):
            return self.f(x) + 10
```

This would be one way. However, this smells very much like decorating! What would be the proper pythonic way to do this?

Comment: I think the way you wrote it is Pythonic enough imho

Comment: That's very different from decorating. A decorator changes what a function does, so in the end you have 1 function. But you want to have 2 functions.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I politely disagree. IMHO, decorating is at the end nothing else than composition of functions. Which is exactly what I do above, IMHO.

Comment: It may be composition, but it still results in exactly 1 function and not 2.

Comment: If I had a decorator like `add10`, I probably wouldn't use decorator syntax to define the function. Instead, I'd just write `g = add10(f)`

Comment: Composition is just a special case of decoration; the decorator doesn't have to call `f`, or return a wrapper around `f`, or even *use* `f`. It's just syntactic sugar for function *application*.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can write a simple function outside the class:

```
def add_val(f):
  def wrapper(cls, _x):
    return f(cls, _x) + 10
  return wrapper


class A:
  @add_val
  def f(self, x):
    return 2*x 
print(A().f(20))
```

Output:

```
50
```

Edit: you can utilize `functools.wraps` with a `classmethod` in Python3. The wrapped function `f` will return `x*2` and the decorator `g` will add `10` to the returned result of the function passed to it. However, to be able to save the original functionality of `f`, you can utilize the `__wrapped__` attribute:

```
import functools
def g(f):
  @functools.wraps(f)
  def wrapper(cls, _x):
    return f(cls, _x)+10
  return wrapper

class A:
   @classmethod
   @g
   def f(cls, x):
     return x*2

f_1 = functools.partial(A.f.__wrapped__, A)
print(A.f(4))
print(f_1(4))
```

Output:

```
18
8
```

Comment: So your `f` is the OP's `g`, and the OP's `f` disappeared into nirvana? I don't think this is what the OP wants. Also, you should really use [functools.wraps](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps) when you write decorators.

Comment: thanks for your answer. However, I would like to have a class method for both results, i.e. 2*x and 2*x + 10. Is this possible?

Comment: @Aran-Fey No, `f` is the same. The decorator is adding additional functionality to `f` by providing the same operation as `g`.

Comment: @math I am not sure I entirely understand, but it seems to me that you are trying to decorate `f` by applying the operation in `g` (adding `10` to the returned result of `f` ) yet still retaining the unwrapped function `f`. Please see my recent edit, as I added another possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Extending answer of @Ajax1234, you may try to:
 - parametrize your decorator,
 - call your decorator explicitly (without `@`).

```
def add_val(_value):
  def decorator(f):
    def wrapper(cls, _x):
      return f(cls, _x) + _value
    return wrapper

  return decorator

class A:
  def f(self, x):
    return 2*x 

  g = add_val(10)(f)
```

[EDIT]

You may also improve the decorator with `functools.wraps()` (which is a decorator itself). All you need to do is to change your wrapper declaration:

```
@functools.wraps(f)
def wrapper(cls, _x):
  return f(cls, _x) + _value
```

Comment: If you're going to teach someone how to use decorators, *please* use [`functools.wraps`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.wraps).

Comment: @Aran-Fey I thought it is optional. Is it to comply with some Python standard or just for convenience?

Comment: It does some nice things like copy the wrapped function's name and docstring. It also makes it possible to access the wrapped function through the `__wrapped__` attribute. `wraps` is what makes the difference between a function that returns another function, and a good, proper decorator.

Comment: @Aran-Fey I agree it is convenient (and I do use it in my code), but according to [Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/glossary.html#term-decorator) decorator is exactly _"a function that returns another function"_.